# How to compare the content of two files in EFI Shell

Tags: shell, uefi

I want to compare the content of two files in EFI Shell.
I saved the content of *pci 05 00 00* in lan-ref.txt

My script looks like this:

```
echo -off
fs0:

pci 05 00 00 -s 0 > lan.txt

if lan.txt == lan-ref.txt then
  reset
else
  echo "LAN not found"
endif
```

I know that the "if lan.txt == lan-ref.txt" is not going to work, I am looking for the correct line to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: There is a comp command, but I don’t know if it can be used in an if. Maybe by using %lasterror%?

Answer (score 3):

Like @prl suggests, combine the `comp` command and `%lasterror%`:

```
comp lan-text lan-ref.txt
if %lasterror% eq 0 then
  reset
else
  echo "LAN not found"
endif
```

%lasterror% is equivalent to %errorlevel% in `.bat` scripts or `$?` in bourne shells and derivatives.

Answer (score -1):

```
comp lan-text lan-ref.txt 
if %lasterror% ==0 then 
  reset
else
   echo "LAN not found"
endif
```